# Over using 'this' in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am just starting to learn typescript/Angular having come from a c++/java background having never touched any web development stuff before. I wrote a small piece of code with some FormControls and someone made a suggested improvement that I don't understand.

The code is as follows:

```
this.myFormData = { ...data };    
this.myForm.controls['name'].setValue(this.myFormData.name);
this.myForm.controls['address'].setValue(this.myFormData.address);
this.myForm.controls['age'].setValue(this.myFormData.age);
this.myForm.controls['gender'].setValue(this.myFormData.gender);
this.myForm.controls['mailing_list'].setValue(this.myFormData.mailing_list);
```

I've been told that I should change it to:

```
this.myFormData = { ...data };
const formControls = this.myForm.controls;
formControls['name'].setValue(this.myFormData.name);
formControls['address'].setValue(this.myFormData.address);
formControls['age'].setValue(this.myFormData.age);
formControls['gender'].setValue(this.myFormData.gender);
formControls['mailing_list'].setValue(this.myFormData.mailing_list);
```

with the reason being it would save memory. I questioned this point thinking it was maybe some premature optimization but the peer reviewer is sure that accessing 'this' and searching for 'myForm' and getting 'controls' each time is bad practice stating the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle of software development.

I am still learning so I guess I should just take the reviewers word for it but I really do want to understand the difference in the example posted and why one was better than the other. I have searched online for an answer but i'm not having any success (maybe due to not knowing the technical terms to search for?).

An explanation for a novice would be great or links to where I could find an answer would help too.

Comment: The only perk I can think of is shortened syntax :)

Comment: Hmm. After this transformation, the source code is 1 byte longer. If this code is not in a loop that runs it thousands of times, I don't see how this could save memory.  I would ask the reviewer how one can verify that it indeed saves memory.

Comment: The reviewer does realize that Typescript is a transpiled language, right?

Comment: I agree with @justMe, if you have a lot of access to `this.myForm.controls` I would put in a variable just because it looks nicer, but as far as performance goes you may be right about premature optimization, I don't think this should make much of a difference. Ask your reviewer to answer here on SO if he can, I'd really like to hear the explanation, he may have some interesting insight  :)

Comment: @KennethK. Since he is a beginner he might not, I added the JS tag as that is probably more relevant for the question since this is runtime behavior, but the question stands for JS I think.

Comment: Regarding performance: [In javascript, is accessing 'window.Math' slower or faster than accessing the 'Math' object without the 'window.'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2125113) is a very similar discussion, although there is some discussion around the global object that is tangential. (also on point: [Why do people use variables in some cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42172002)). Basically, as with all performance topics, the best advice is "measure it and see".

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html : "all declarations other than those you plan to modify should use const. The rationale is that if a variable didn’t need to get written to, others working on the same codebase shouldn’t automatically be able to write to the object, and will need to consider whether they really need to reassign to the variable". Using const TypeScript don't spend time to reasigning

Comment: I would use the second one (using const to save this) because of one thing: your element name.
If tomorow you change the form from, myForm to mySecondForm, you will have only one change to make.
But nothing about optimization, maybe redeability, but that's all

Comment: Personally instead of using `this.myForm.controls['name']` I'd use `this.myForm.get('name')`.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir The reviewer has told me that not storing selections is considered rule violations by SonarQube for JS which lead them to make the comments on my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular uses Uglify which will rewrite the following code.

Before Uglify

```
this.myFormData = { ...data };    
this.myForm.controls['name'].setValue(this.myFormData.name);
this.myForm.controls['address'].setValue(this.myFormData.address);
this.myForm.controls['age'].setValue(this.myFormData.age);
this.myForm.controls['gender'].setValue(this.myFormData.gender);
this.myForm.controls['mailing_list'].setValue(this.myFormData.mailing_list);
```

After Uglify

```
this.a={ ...data };this.b.controls['name'].setValue(this.a.name);this.b.controls['address'].setValue(this.a.address);this.b.controls['age'].setValue(this.a.age);this.b.controls['gender'].setValue(this.a.gender);this.b.controls['mailing_list'].setValue(this.a.mailing_list);
```

This happens automatically for you in Angular and it accounts for far more performance gains than you can get from minimizing your use of `this`, but the problem here isn't the *references* to memory. It's the larger files the source code generates.

Let's rewrite the source code to favor minification instead.

```
const data = { ...data };    
const controls = this.myForm.controls;
controls['name'].setValue(data.name);
controls['address'].setValue(data.address);
controls['age'].setValue(data.age);
controls['gender'].setValue(data.gender);
controls['mailing_list'].setValue(data.mailing_list);
```

This will minify like this:

```
const a={ ...data };const b=this.myForm.controls;b['name'].setValue(a.name);b['address'].setValue(a.address);b['age'].setValue(a.age);b['gender'].setValue(a.gender);b['mailing_list'].setValue(a.mailing_list);
```

From a CPU performance perspective there is no difference in measurable speed between your two source code examples.

From a file size perspective there would be a gain that can be measure in bytes. It's something you gain when you write the source code, and most people don't have time to go back later and rewrite lines of code just to get a few bytes in minification.

Reducing a large project just by 100kb can make a big difference on how long it takes for the application to start up.

Comment: thanks. Searching uglify and minify lead me to find out about --no-delete-output-path on the build. It was very interesting to see how the code looks afterwards and no doubt will serve me well for my future learning.

Answer (score 3):

[Binding this](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-bindthisvalue) and [binding const variableName](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-declarative-environment-records-createimmutablebinding-n-s) are both entries in the [enviroment record](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-environment-records). So creating a extra variable in the enviroment record for something that is already in there uses more memory.

If you look at [8.1.1.3.4GetThisBinding()](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-environment-records-getthisbinding) compared to [8.1.1.4.6GetBindingValue ( N, S )](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-global-environment-records-getbindingvalue-n-s) the `this` lookup does one extra step `[[ThisBindingStatus]] is not "lexical"`. So you could argue that using `this` is slower since it has an extra comparison, but I would argue that processors are very quick at doing comparisons so it's negligible.

Likewise traversing the object graph with `this.myForm.controls` compared directly accessing the location of controls with `const formControls = this.myForm.controls` is negligible. Property access is not a search, each property corresponds to a location in memory* so there is little overhead to jumping through properties.

I think the reviewer is trying to justify a codding style/preference by saying "uses more memory". They could try to make a sound case for why their method is better but I think they would have been better served just saying that they like cleaning up code by creating a constant to store nested references in so that you don't have long chain access in your code. This is after all essentially what object destructing is, just makes things a bit shorter.

Another solution you could have used is

```
Object.keys(data).forEach((key)=>{
    this.myFormData[key] = data[key];
    this.myFormControls[key].setValue(data[key]);
});
```

This solution looks "cleaner" but introduces the side-effect that data might have more that you were intending to set in your form controls. On the other hand it can be said that this solution is more flexible since it works for any number of key/values and each time you add a property you don't have to go into your code and add another line.

Everything solution has it's pros/cons and there are multiple ways to tackle every problem. The best thing you can do is understand what an algorithm is doing and what the pros/cons of doing it a certain way are.

*probably not 100% true but not bad model to conceptualize property access.

Comment: "So you could argue that using this is slower since it has an extra comparison..." With JITs like V8 or the ones WebKits ships with this would probably even result in the same machine code.